# Chef Knife Rackspace OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket Error

Tags: chef-infra, rackspace-cloud

I am attempting to access my managed cloud instance via my knife tool. When ever I execute a knife rackspace command, the following line is output to my console multiple times before listing the response:
"Excon nonblock is not supported by your OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket"

Have anyone else experienced this issue or do anyone know why or how to fix this?

A second issue I am having, is that when I do a knife "rackspace server list", the list returned is empty even though I do have an active server in the cloud. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this page](https://github.com/geemus/excon/issues/13):

There are two workarounds.  First choice is better than second if you can manage it.

1) fix ca_path to cert path: `Excon.ssl_ca_path = '/path/to/certs'`

2) turn off peer verification: `Excon.ssl_verify_peer = false`

Both apply to your `knife.rb` file.

You could also check: [this README](https://github.com/opscode/knife-rackspace/blob/master/README.rdoc) and [this wiki entry](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Launch+Cloud+Instances+with+Knife)